# Is it possible to track FPS and other system information for external games?

Tags: cross-platform, monitoring, hardware, desktop, haxe

So I have an idea for a desktop application which I won't go into depth on. But part of it requires me to be able to monitor various hardware processes, CPU, FPS, Utilization etc from Haxe?

Lets say a person installs this program on his computer and runs it in the background, decides to play a game of Bioshock? Is it possible for me to be able to monitor the hardware from my application?

If this is possible how would I go about searching for this or implementing this, my searches have led me to sites and questions about various programs which do this already which all use this information for a different purpose.

I would like to keep this cross-platform, but if this is simply not an option I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction!